# Constructor injection with Quartz.NET 3.0.3 and Simple Injector How To

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, quartz.net, simple-injector

I am trying to use Quartz.Net v3.0.3 and Simple Injector in a windows service.

I have a job class below which i would like to inject some dependencies such as my logger into.

```
public class JobWorker :  IJob
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public JobWorker(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>_logger.Log("Do Work"));
    }
}
```

I tried registering `Container.Register<IJob, JobWorker>();` on my DI layer but this doesn't help.

If i remove the injected dependency and simply use the default parameterless constructor the job fires correct.

Accord to the post below by Steven, the suggestion is to create a Factory, however the answer provided is out of date in context of the new framework and i'm completely lost as how to inject dependencies into jobs.

[Constructor injection with Quartz.NET and Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562176/constructor-injection-with-quartz-net-and-simple-injector)

Comment: you still have to implement your own JobFactory. The job factory that is included by default only supports parameterless constructors.

Comment: Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158004/6666799](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158004/6666799) for an example how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

The link provided by @Rabban is still valid and using `IServiceProvider` is a good design choice, but you can use whatever concrete Container you want.

Here are my 2c based on Rabban's answer using `Quartz 3.0.4` and `SimpleInjector 4.2.1`:

```
using NLog;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Spi;
using System;

namespace My.Dear.App.Infrastructure
{

    public class SomeJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private static ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public DexJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            try
            {
                IJobDetail jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
                Type jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
                logger.Debug($"Producing instance of Job '{jobDetail.Key}', class={jobType.FullName}");

                return serviceProvider.GetService(jobType) as IJob;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, Constants.ErrorAt, nameof(IJobFactory.NewJob));
                throw new SchedulerException($"Problem instantiating class '{bundle.JobDetail.JobType.FullName}'", ex);
            }
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            var disposable = job as IDisposable;
            disposable?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm for me.

How to get an instance?

```
public static async Task RegisterQuartz(Container container)
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    IJobFactory jobFactory = new SomeJobFactory(container);
    scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;

    container.RegisterInstance(schedulerFactory);
    container.RegisterInstance(jobFactory);
    container.RegisterInstance(scheduler);
    container.Register<IDearJob, DearJob>();
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to register your Jobs. Otherwise it may not work.

I suggest creating an Interface for each Job and not using `Quartz IJob` for that.

```
public interface IDearJob : IJob { }

public interface DearJob : IDearJob 
{
    private readonly ISomeService service;

    public DearJob(ISomeService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) 
    {
        // retrieve context if you need
        await this.service.DoSomethingAsync(/*params*/);
    }
}
```

Now you can use a breakpoint on Execute.
Cheers.

**EDIT**

P.S.: Steven answer is very good and I think you can play with it to update that context to yours.
Now serious, cheers.